How to Display a Progress Bar for adb Pull from Device to PC Using PowerShell
I want to use adb pull on Windows 10 to transfer files from my Nothing 2a (Android 14) or Realme X3SZ (Android 12) to my PC using PowerShell. Although the files are being copied successfully, even with the -p flag, there is no visible progress bar. The cursor simply blinks continuously.
I would like to know how to add a progress bar to see the percentage of files being pulled or pushed from or onto a device.
I have read the following discussion:
How to effectively transfer files from PC to an Android phone
However, despite following the instructions, I still don't see a progress bar in PowerShell on Windows 10.
